# How to make mouse wheel scroll the less pager using bash and gnome-terminal?

Tags: bash, scrolling, less, gnome-terminal

I have two computers with the latest Fedora. On the first, I'm using zsh and the mouse wheel can be used with the less pager within gnome-terminal to scroll the pager.

On the second, I use bash and the mouse whell scroll the terminal history, not the pager.

The shell shouldn't make any difference, why can't I use the mouse wheel to scroll in the second case?

To illustrate what it does, imagine I have a document like this:

```
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
DDDD
EEEE
```

And I have a two line terminal. If I use less, I get on the screen

```
AAAA
BBBB
```

The mouse wheeel cannot scroll further down. If I scroll upwards, I get the bash prompt history. Now I use the page down key to get to the bottom of the document, I get on screen:

```
DDDD
EEEE
```

Scrolling upwards gets me

```
BBBB
DDDD
```

-->

Comment: On Guake 0.4.4 (Ubuntu 14.04) there ia a bug that has already been fixed upstream: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/guake/+bug/1370762

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The computer where `less` scrolled had `LESS=-r`,
the other had `LESS=-asXFMMRqix8`.

From [the `less` man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/less.1.html):

> `-q` or `--quiet` or `--silent`
>
>     Causes  moderately  "quiet"  operation: the terminal bell is not
>                     rung if an attempt is made to scroll past the end of the file or
>                     before the beginning of the file.  If the terminal has a "visual
>                     bell", it is used instead.  The bell will  be  rung  on  certain
>                     other  errors, such as typing an invalid character.  The default
>                     is to ring the terminal bell in all such cases.
>
> `-X` or `--no-init`
>
>     Disables sending the termcap initialization and deinitialization
>                     strings  to  the  terminal.   This is sometimes desirable if the
>                     deinitialization string does something unnecessary,
>       like  clearing the screen.

The `-X` option prevented scrolling all together and the `-q` option caused the pager to enter a non-scrollable state when scrolling past the beginning or end of file.

My options are now `LESS=-asrRix8`.

Comment: Ugh. So disappointing: I love `-XE`, because I love having small files immediately dumped at the prompt, i.e. using `less` as a `cat` replacement for small files. I wish I could have `-XE` behaviour *with* scrolling on longer files … e-mailed the author in hopes this is something achievable. I suspect not. >:

Comment: I use `export LESS='-RiF --mouse --wheel-lines=3'`.

Answer (score 20):

```
export LESS='--mouse --wheel-lines=3'
```

Comment: Please add context to this answer (i.e. what file this should be added to or if you're intending for it to be entered directly into a terminal as a standalone command)

Comment: Also worth mentioning that this solution requires version 5.4.3+ of `less`

Comment: `There is no mouse --wheel-lines=3 option ("less --help" for help)`

Comment: @alper: That depends or which version of less you have I guess. My Arch installation supports that option

Comment: You probably need to upgrade your less for this flag to work (I had to). My system (MacOS 12.1) had _less 487_. Latest version is _less 590_. http://www.greenwoodsoftware.com/less/

Answer (score 7):

For those who are as a newbie like me, you have to enter the following to your terminal:

```
export LESS=-r
```

or use this:

```
export LESS=-R
```

you can use `man less` to see the difference

To have the effect persist, you can add this line to your `~/.bashrc` and reopen your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't know why, but unsetting this var does it. Other suggested answers however don't work.

```
unset LESS
```

`less -V` gives the following,

```
less 458 (POSIX regular expressions)
Copyright (C) 1984-2012 Mark Nudelman
```

Comment: You probably had some option already set then. What would `echo $LESS` give before unsetting it?