# Scroll "less" output using scroll wheel on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, osx-mountain-lion, scrolling, less, scroll-wheel

How can I enable the scrolling of "less" output (rather than the terminal window itself) using the scroll wheel on OSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** Seems that this is now supported automatically in OS X Yosemite or newer. Just use `less` and scroll.

---

For earlier versions of OS X:

You can't scroll using the mouse wheel without any hacks. One of these makes use of a SIMBL plugin called [MouseTerm](https://bitheap.org/mouseterm/), which reports the mouse events to your Terminal:

> MouseTerm is a SIMBL plugin for Mac OS X's Terminal.app that passes
>   mouse events to the terminal, allowing you to use mouse shortcuts
>   within applications that support them.
>
> To get started, first install [SIMBL](http://www.culater.net/software/SIMBL/SIMBL.php) (MouseTerm won't work without
>   it!). Once you've done that, open the .dmg file, run Install, and
>   restart Terminal.app. To uninstall, run Uninstall from the .dmg.

The FAQ mentions `less` as a good place to try mouse reporting.

Comment: As an update to this question, I have since learned that "less" belongs to a family of applications called pagers. You can set your default pager in your .bashrc file in most Unices, and there are options outside of less that do support scrolling with the mouse wheel. `mcview` is one example, but there are others as well.

Comment: `less -r` works without anything additional like SIMBL.

Comment: (It could well be that OSX Terminal has evolved since this answer was posted. I'm running Yosemite)

Comment: Yeah, it works now, even without `-r`.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Ended up just using [mcview](http://www.midnight-commander.org/) for my viewer, for which mouse scrolling in the terminal worked out of the box. I've also [read](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=58448) that [most](http://www.jedsoft.org/most/) can support scrolling behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I tried `less -r` as given in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/455213/72975) and it worked great (scrolling with the standard trackpad gesture.)

See also [this similar question](https://superuser.com/q/961719/72975) which discusses some limitations.

Actually, looking more carefully at the second link, it's really the *absence* of `-X` that's critical to being able to have scrolling behavior (which means that if you want fancy scrolling, you can't keep the output in the terminal history after `less` quits.)