# Less seems to no longer accept mouse-scrolls in the Terminal in macOS

Tags: macos, terminal, mouse, scrolling, terminal.app

For a few years now, **Terminal.app** in macOS has supported mouse-scrolling with the `less` program, but today I noticed that it is no longer accepting mouse scrolls, and only works with the <kbd>Up</kbd> and <kbd>Down</kbd> keys now. My installed version of `less` via macOS is version 487.

---

### What's not working:

**`less`** and all other programs that use it are not accepting mouse scrolls. Instead, it scrolls the terminal window. These 'other' programs are:

- `man`
- `git log`
- `diff`

Previously, `less` would also clear the screen when closing it (`q`), but now the text remains on the screen.

---

### What I've tried:

- **Tested other programs:** `vim` for example, still accepts mouse scrolls
- **Used other Terminal emulators:** `less` is not accepting mouse scrolls on `Hyper` either
- **Tested on another machine over SSH:** Connected to one of my VPSes, and used `less` there within the Terminal app. Mouse-scrolls are working with it.
- **Used a newer version of less:** Installed the latest version (530) of less using **Homebrew**, but it's not working with mouse scrolls either.

So I'm not sure what's wrong. Would greatly appreciate any help to make `less` accept mouse scrolls again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After going through a few other answers, I've realized there is a `$LESS` environment variable that contains default flags.

It's empty on my other Mac and Ubuntu system, but for some reason it's equal to **`-FRX`** on this machine, **and that's causing these issues**:

- `-X` caused it to **NOT** accept mouse scrolls
- `-F` caused it to automatically exit for small files

Which is weird, since I never changed it, so it must've been modified by some other program. Anyways, manually setting it in my `.rc` files fixed the issue:

```
export LESS="-R"
```

---

Sources:

- Unix & Linux: [Neither 'less' or 'less -X' clear screen on exit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/156348/neither-less-or-less-x-clear-screen-on-exit)
- SuperUser: [Less command clearing screen upon exit](https://superuser.com/questions/106637/less-command-clearing-screen-upon-exit-how-to-switch-it-off)

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/q/961719/278816 to clarify that `less` cannot handle mouse at all, the `-X` option just indirectly causes mouse events not to be handled (by the terminal emulator, and not by less) as one would expect.

Comment: For iTerm users, `Preferences`->`Advanced`-> search and enable `Scroll wheel sends arrow keys when in alternate screen mode` to YES.