# In less cmd, I cannot use mouse to select characters expect press Shift button. Why?

Tags: mouse, windows-subsystem-for-linux, less

Refered to [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/455212/how-to-make-mouse-wheel-scroll-the-less-pager-using-bash-and-gnome-terminal), I had set `export LESS='-riF --mouse --wheel-lines=3'`, and solved the scrolling problem, but I coundn't select any charaters on the screen except pressing SHIFT button.

This is inconvenient，can anyone help me solve this?

I use it in WSL, zsh.

Comment: Same question. I think this is probably due to how Windows Terminal handles text selection, but I'd prefer to be able to select text even if scrolling will deselect it. The `Shift` button workaround isn't really viable because once any selection exists you cannot deselect so every future click becomes a text selection modification, rather than a new selection.